# How can I use objects as keys in a JSON?

Tags: java, json, gson, user-input, javascript-objects

I have this neat data format which is best represented with objects as keys. So I tried to use the following JSON:

```
{
  "blocks": {
    "stone": {
      {
        "variant": ["bricks", "smooth"]
      }: {
        "sound": "guitar",
        "particle": "guitar",
      }
    },
    "dirt": {
      {
        "variant": "dirt"
      }: {
        "sound": "square",
        "particle": "note",
        "volume": 0.5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it gives me a JsonSyntaxException. I'm using GSON btw. How can I make this work?

The data structures:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Instrument {
  private final String name;
  private final String particle;
  private final float volume;
  public Instrument(String name, Optional<String> particle, Optional<Float> volume) {
    this.name = name;
    this.particle = particle.orElse("note");
    this.volume = volume.orElse(1.0f);
  }
  /* getters and stuff */
}
```

---

```
public class BlockType {
  private final String name;
  private final BlockStateMatcher state;
  public BlockType(String name, BlockStateMatcher state) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
  }
  /* getters and stuff */
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class BlockStateMatcher {
  private final Map<PropertyMap, Instrument> states;
  /* etc */
}
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
public class PropertyMap extends HashMap<Property<T>, List<PropertyValue<T>>> /* simplified */ {
  /* etc */
}
```

Comment: It's not valid JSON syntax. See http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @ScaryWombat Can't I just use this syntax somehow?

Comment: Sure but it is not json.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Well how do I make it work?

Comment: see my answer i.e. produce valid json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. It's not valid JSON syntax.

As per the [documentation](http://www.json.org/), the object keys need to be strings, and according to the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4):

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.

Comment: Well is there really no way to make GSON accept this kind of JSON?

Comment: @SoniEx2, It's not a kind of JSON, so no.

Comment: You can probably hack GSON to get it to accomplish your needs, but what you want to parse is simply not JSON.

Comment: It's not JSON because it doesn't follow the JSON spec, no matter what it looks like.

Comment: Eh any way I can do it with stock GSON? I can't modify the GSON I'm using

Comment: You will not be able to parse your non-JSON format with any standard JSON parser. Either change your format, find a more flexible parser, or write your own parser.

Answer (score 1):

The text that you have provided is not valid json.

If your text was

```
{
    "blocks": [{
        "name": "stone",
        "variant": "bricks",
        "sound": "guitar",
        "particle": "guitar"
    }, {
        "name": "dirt",
        "variant": "dirt",
        "sound": "square",
        "particle": "note",
        "volume": 0.5
    }]
}
```

you might be able to parse it.